# Batch Update From a LINQ Query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Right now I have an application that processes records in a DB one record at a time.

```
var records = from q in db.table 
              join j in db.OtherTable 
              where q.processed == 0 //Sample 
foreach(var record in records)
{
    //Do some stuff....

    db.ExecuteCommand("Update table set record.processed = 1 where id = record.ID");
}
```

At the end of the foreach it updates the record as processed. Obviously because LINQ does not do a great job at updates I just do an executeCommand. Now it is a requirement that this application run quickly. Right now that "Do some stuff" takes less than a second running through thousands of rows, it even inserts a record into a table using SqlBulkCopy.

The problem is that when I put in the code to update that the record is processed, it slows it down significantly. It has to update the database thousands of times. What would be a faster way to update all of the records that I selected (and only the records I selected) without too much of a loss of speed. (Note: it's okay if after the whole process is done (after the foreach) if that it takes a bit of time).

Comment: can you update whole of the records in db after end of foreach? or you want do it on every iteration immediately?

Comment: Are you really updating EVERY RECORD in the table within the `foreach` loop?  Is there some sort of identifier to use to only update one record?

Comment: Why not update your entities the call `SubmitChanges`?

Comment: Hamlet, as because I'm not selecting the actual entity (a class named table in the above context), updating it does no good I believe.

Yes D, every record needs to be updated that it has been processed, because this process is going to immediately run again, I can't select the same records.

Updating at the end of the foreach is just fine.

Comment: @KJ3 My point was that you _were_ updating the entire table in each loop - which you have corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could generate an `IN` statement based on the IDs in your list:

```
string ids = string.Join(", ", records.Select(r => r.RecordID));
string sql = string.Format("Update table set record.processed = 1 WHERE RecordID IN ({0}) ", ids)
db.ExecuteCommand(sql);
```

Comment: Mistake on my part, I left off the where ID = record.ID in my example query. Nonetheless, this is a good looking solution, will give it a shot and report back.

Comment: OK I took that part of my answer out.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, runs very efficiently and doesn't bog down the process. Thanks! Didn't know about the string.join function